# Check if a file is archive (zip or rar) using php

Tags: php

How can i check if a file is archived (zip or rar) without knowing the extension. I need to find it using php.

I cannot use Fileinfo because its not installed and installation of any other packages on the server its out of the question.

UPDATE:

Zip module its not installed and i cannot install extra packages.
I don't want to use mime_content_type because its deprecated

Thank you

Comment: mime_content_type but its deprecated and Fileinfo its not installed on the server and i cannot install it.

Comment: $zip = zip_open($file);    if(is_resource($zip)){ //its zip } else { //its not zip }  | but for rar I'm not sure

Comment: You should mention this in your question so that you won't get answers suggesting to use `Fileinfo`. Obviously, the more information you provide, the better answers you will get.

Comment: If Fileinfo is not installed, then install it. Otherwise re-invent the wheel and write it your own for the file-types in question. Or use google for some existing library for that.

Comment: rar and zip both have magic numbers in the first few bytes of the file. Easy enough to read 10 bytes or so and check for those numbers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Output from `od -c`:

```
  0000000    R   a   r   ! 032  \a  \0 317 220   s  \0  \0  \r  \0  \0  \0

  0000000    P   K 003 004  \n  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   !  \0  \0  \0
```

You could use something like this:

```
<?php

$fh = @fopen($argv[1], "r");

if (!$fh) {
  print "ERROR: couldn't open file.\n";
  exit(126);
}

$blob = fgets($fh, 5);

fclose($fh);

if (strpos($blob, 'Rar') !== false) {
  print "Looks like a Rar.\n";
} else
if (strpos($blob, 'PK') !== false) {
  print "Looks like a ZIP.\n";
} else {
  print "I dunno.\n";
  exit(1);
}

?>
```

And my output:

```
ghoti@baz:~ 423$ ./filephp.php A2.rar
Looks like a Rar.
ghoti@baz:~ 424$ ./filephp.php OLDIE.zip 
Looks like a ZIP.
ghoti@baz:~ 425$ ./filephp.php 1-11-1.PDF 
I dunno.
ghoti@baz:~ 426$
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Fish!

Comment: strpos($blob, 'PK') !== false returns true for .odt (OpenDocument) files.

Comment: @om1 .. yes. OpenDocument files are ZIP files. Try `unzip -v yadda.odt` to see what's inside. If you want to correctly identify the *contents* of a ZIP file, you need to look further than the first five bytes.

Answer (score 7):

To test whether a file is a zip archive, you can attempt to open it as a zip using `open_zip` function.  For rar, you need to have PECL rar (preferably version at least 2.0.0) installed - see http://php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php for more details.  The code could look like this:

```
if(is_resource($zip = zip_open($filename)))
{
    zip_close($zip);
    //this is a zip archive
}
elseif(($rar = RarArchive::open($filename)) !== FALSE)
{
    $rar->close();
    //this is a rar archive
}
else
{
    //this is not a zip or rar archive
}
```

You may need to do a bit extra work if the archives are password-protected.  Read the corresponding php manual pages for more details.

Comment: Btw missing parantheses for 1st if

Comment: Also, this will return `this is a zip` if the file is of zero size. Use `if(filesize($zipfile)==0) return false;` to return `this is not a zip`

Comment: @RenanCavalieri My example is not a production code - but a demonstration of what can be done.

Comment: As of PHP 8 the function zip_open() is depreciated. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php

Comment: The new PHP functionality for opening a zip is: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php

Answer (score 2):

The [fileinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) functions should help you with this, by checking the file's mime type:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
echo finfo_file($finfo, $filename); // This will return the mime-type
finfo_close($finfo);
```

Comment: This tends to fail on Office 2007+ documents (DOCX, XLSX, PPTX) on some systems so that a manual check is inevitable.

Answer (score 2):

You could output the info from unix file command and parse it(assuming you can execute system commands, which is bad practice).

This is example of centos "file *filename*" output.

> [rr@localhost images] (master)# file ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif
>   ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif: GIF image data, version 89a, 16 x 16
>
> [rr@localhost images] (master)# file ui-icons_454545_256x240.png
>   ui-icons_454545_256x240.png: PNG image data, 256 x 240, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
>
> [rr@localhost vendors] (master)# file jquery-validation-1.9.0.zip
>   jquery-validation-1.9.0.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract

also like other people suggested, you could read few bytes and check if they match signature.

for rar

> Identifying characters Hex: 52 61 72 21 1A 07 00 , ASCII: Rar!

for zip

> Identifying characters Hex: 50 4B 03 04 , ASCII: PK

Answer (score 2):

Read first 10 bytes of the file. If they are (80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0) it is a ZIP file.
RAR files have the following 7 first bytes: (82, 97, 114, 33, 26, 7, 0)
If you open a ZIP file in a text editor (for instance, Notepad++) you will see:
PK[ETX][EOT][DC4][NUL][NUL][NUL][BS][NUL]....-> the Ascii codes for the characters are listed above.
For the RAR files the picture is:
Rar![SUB][BEL][NUL]....
So, just read the 10 first bytes of a file and you can tell if it is ZIP or RAR archive.
Cheers

Comment: if the question is about checking it php, i don't know what notepad++ or any text editor related solutions help..

Comment: You should only check the first 4 bytes against "\x50\x4b\x03\x04" as they are the sole signature of a PKZip file. The 5th and the 6th byte for example indicate the PKZip version needed for extraction (in your example 2.0) and that may vary. See: [The structure of a ZIP file](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html#localheader)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function isZipFile($filepath){
    $fh = fopen($filepath,'r');
    $bytes = fread($fh,4);
    fclose($fh);
    return ('504b0304' === bin2hex($bytes));
}
```

Thanks to [flu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098678/check-if-a-file-is-archive-zip-or-rar-using-php/63255883#comment27355437_13183424) for the helpful link to the zip file specification.