# How to check zip file or not in php

Tags: php

I am creating zip and rar file posting script in PHP. I want to check before uploading file zip or rar my script not checking any file. when i added zip but it every time display this message `this is not a zip file`

Here is my code

```
if(!empty($_FILES['zip']['tmp_name'][0])){
$zipType = array('application/zip');
$zip = $_FILES['zip']['tmp_name'][0];
if(!in_array($zip, $zipType)){
die("this is not a zip file");
}
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Please help me i have tried to create it not working help me

Comment: `$_FILES['zip']['tmp_name']` contains a filename, of which you're getting the first character. While `$_FILES` _does_ contain the MIME type, it's what the uploader _claims_ that it is, and you cannot trust it. You're going to want: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: Your title asks how to verify a file type but you seem to be struggling with basic file upload. Fix one thing at a time. You can't check a file until you upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the typpe of the uploading file as

```
if(!empty($_FILES['zip']['tmp_name'])){
$zip = $_FILES['zip']['type'];
if($zip !== 'zip')){
die("this is not a zip file");
}
}
```

And to check your file size and limit it till 10mb

```
if(!empty($_FILES['zip']['tmp_name'])){
$zip = $_FILES['zip']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['zip']['size'];
if($zip !== 'zip')){
die("this is not a zip file");
}
if($size > 10000000){
echo 'File is too large';
 }
}
```

And i think there's no need to create an array here.

Comment: can you one more help? how to check file size

Comment: To check the file size you can use `$_FILES['zip']['size']`.

Comment: And if my answer helped you can you please accept it.

Comment: i dont know how to add to my code can you show me please help me

Comment: how do you want it to be?

Comment: Do you want to check the file size too?

Comment: i want to add  10mb file size check

Comment: For this you can try for `if($zip !== 'zip' && $_FILES['zip']['size']  <= '1000000' )`.

Comment: Its 10 lakh because the size is returned in bytes and we have to convert it in the megabytes here.

Comment: how to check one mb numbers

Comment: I did not get your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(is_resource($zip = zip_open($filename))
{
    zip_close($zip);
    //this is a zip archive
}
else(($rar = RarArchive::open($filename)) !== FALSE)
{
    $rar->close();
    //this is a rar archive
}
else
{
    //this is not a zip or rar archive
}
```

[Check if a file is archive (zip or rar) using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098678/check-if-a-file-is-archive-zip-or-rar-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

Use [mime-content-type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

```
$type = mime_content_type($filename);
```

However, if these are files being uploaded then this is wasteful as you need to wait for the user to upload the file before checking it. You should use the filereader api in your html to check the file before it's uploaded. You can check file type, magic bytes, md5 hash etc in browser to accept/reject/validate the file before and after upload