# How to check if a file is an archive before uploading it to a server?

Tags: php

I need to check if a file that's about to be uploaded via input field is really an archive. For images I can just do *$my_image['type']* to get the type, but if I do the same for a .rar file the returned type is '**application/octet-stream**'. I've tried to open the file to check if it's an archive, only to find out later that apparently that can't be done to a file before it's uploaded.

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Ultimately you'll always need to do a server-side check *after* the file has been uploaded. Before the upload, you can only do client-side checks, which can all be circumvented by someone who really wants to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a file is archive (zip or rar) using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098678/check-if-a-file-is-archive-zip-or-rar-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `pathinfo()` function to get the file extension then check if it is an extension that corresponds to an archive file format that you want to support

```
$fileInfo = pathinfo($_FILES["my_file"]["name"]);
$fileExt  = $fileInfo["extension"];

if($fileExt == "zip" || $fileExt == "rar" || $fileExt == "tar" || $fileExt == "gz")
    // your file is an archive
else
    // your file is not an archive
```

You can also try another solution by using `mime_content_type` to get the MIME type of your uploaded file and check if it corresponds to an archive file format

Comment: Ideally, you would want to check the file header. An extension is no guarantee that is the actual file type.